# Pandas conditional group by

Tags: pandas

My dataframe look like this:

```
datetime              Owner    Weight   Score
2020-11-01 00:00:00    AC       40      40
2020-11-01 03:00:00    AC       40      50
2020-11-01 12:00:00    AC       30      45
2020-11-02 06:00:00    AC       20      30
2020-11-02 12:00:00    AC       20      30
2020-11-02 18:00:00    AC       20      30
```

I want to aggregate over each date.

Expected output:

```
date                  Owner    Weight   Score
2020-11-01             AC       110      135
2020-11-02             AC       60       90
```

How I am doing:

1. I am extracting date from datetime
2. grouping over data and owner (after dropping datetime)
   Any better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) and aggregate `sum`:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

df1 = df.groupby([df['datetime'].dt.date.rename('date'), 'Owner']).sum().reset_index()
print (df1)
         date Owner  Weight  Score
0  2020-11-01    AC     110    135
1  2020-11-02    AC      60     90
```

Alternative solution with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

df1 = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='D'), 'Owner']).sum().reset_index()
print (df1)
    datetime Owner  Weight  Score
0 2020-11-01    AC     110    135
1 2020-11-02    AC      60     90
```